# Django How to Install Forked App

Tags: python, django, git, github, django-models

I've forked an app on GitHub to add my own customizations. I'd now like to use the fork.

I tried:

```
pip install original_app
pip install -e git+https://github.com/username/original_app.git#egg=original_app
python manage.py syncdb
```

It successfully installs my forked app. But none of my customizations are effective.

Comment: I assume you are pointing to your fork and not to the original

Comment: Did you run `python setup.py sdist` on your version and push the egg to your fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling the app before fetching your forked version? Maybe that's the issue.